# Database Model for journey step

Tags: sql, database, postgresql, model, uml

I want to model a journey with departure, arrival and possible steps like this

```
A -> B -> C -> D
```

To get from one point to another you must specify the type of your transportation.

Can you please help me with the database model

Thank you in advance

Comment: You need to list the things your database will describe. So far you have places, transportation types and trips. Build those three tables first.

Comment: ok Thank you @johnelemans

Comment: In order for this to become a good question you should show the effort from your side and what you have come up with so far. Then you can ask a question about what exactly you are stuck with. Simply *Give me teh codez* is not enough. You should not expect others to do your work for you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A **journey** has a departure and a destination, and is composed of several **steps**, using a given mean of **transportation** to move between two **places**.

This could be represented with a model looking somewhat like: 
 [image].

This could be completed by some constraints such as:

- `from` of the first step must be the same as journey's `departure`,
- `to` of the last step should be the same as `destination`.
- for to consecutive steps, the step's `to` should coincide with the subsqeuent step's `from`

To convert this into a database schema, make each of the classes a table.  You could add a unique id column to the tables journey, places (e.g. to distinguish Paris,Texas and Paris, France) and means of transportation.  FOr steps, the composition relation would be implemented by having a primary key composed of Journey's id and the sequence_number.

Your journey would then look like:

```
 Journey: { 1, A, D } 
 Step:    { 1, 1, A, B, train}
          { 1, 2, B, C, plane}
          { 1, 3, C, D, car}
 ...
```